# QML: How to get the QModelIndex in a delegate inside a TreeView

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qmodelindex

I have a delegate in a qml `TreeView`. I would like to get its `QModelIndex`. Vía

```
 model.index
```

I only get the number of the row, where the delegate is. However, I need to pass a `QModelIndex` to the c++ side (to make a `QPersistentModelIndex` and store it for later use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html#itemDelegate-prop):

> **itemDelegate : Component**
>
> This property defines a delegate to draw a specific cell.
>
> In the item delegate you have access to the following special
>   properties:
>
> ```
> styleData.selected - if the item is currently selected
> styleData.value - the value or text for this item
> styleData.textColor - the default text color for an item
> styleData.row - the index of the view row
> styleData.column - the index of the view column
> styleData.elideMode - the elide mode of the column
> styleData.textAlignment - the horizontal text alignment of the column
> styleData.pressed - true when the item is pressed
> styleData.hasActiveFocus - true when the row has focus
> styleData.index - the QModelIndex of the current item in the model
> styleData.depth - the depth of the current item in the model
> styleData.isExpanded - true when the item is expanded
> styleData.hasChildren - true if the model index of the current item has or can have children
> styleData.hasSibling - true if the model index of the current item has a sibling
> ```

In your case you must use `styleData.index`.