# Qt6 QML Treeview get the modelIndex of selected item

Tags: c++, qml, treeview, qt6.4.1

I have a working treemodel, called `myModel` (derived from `QAbstractItemModel`) in C++ and I can show it in QML using the QML `Treeview` control and the `TreeViewDelegate`

When the mouse is pressed on one treeview item, I want to pass a `QModelIndex` (or parameters which I can use in C++ for constructing a `QModelIndex`) back to C++ for further processing.

I can use the `model.index` but this gives me the index in the view (which corresponds to the selected row), but not a useable `QModelIndex`. Also I experiemented with the depth of the treeview. But I am stuck.

Has anyone a solution?

BTW: I am using Qt6.4. I found something for Qt5, which is now archived ([QML: How to get the QModelIndex in a delegate inside a TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50170037/qml-how-to-get-the-qmodelindex-in-a-delegate-inside-a-treeview)).

This is the code where I try to investigate the behaviour of the treeview (the call to `_controller(...)` is the entry point back to C++:

```
TreeView {
            id: garminDrives
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredHeight: root.height
            Layout.preferredWidth: root.width

            delegate: TreeViewDelegate {

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        console.log("Tree item tapped. Model name = " + model.name
                                    + " Index to be passed back to C++ = " + model.index,
                                    " Depth = " + garminDrives.depth(model.index) + " row =  "
                                    + model.row + " col = " + model.column
                                    + " currentRow = " + garminDrives.currentRow
                                    + " currentCol = " + garminDrives.currentCol
                                    )

                        _controller.getSelectedRow(model.index)
                    }
                }

                contentItem: Label {
                    id: delegatetext
                    text: model.name
                }
            }
            model: myModel
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simplified the QML

```
TreeView {
    id: treeView

    anchors.fill: parent

    delegate: TreeViewDelegate {
        id: treeDelegate
        text: model.display
        onClicked: {

            var mi = treeDelegate.treeView.index(row, column)
            console.log("model.index =", mi)
            treeView.model.showQModelIndex(mi)
        }
    }
    model: _model
}
```

}

The QModelIndex is simply treeDelegate.treeView.index(row, column).

You can find the complete example on Github: https://github.com/d029940/QmlTreeview

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that row of the TreeViewDelegate was valid, but column was undefined. (If you have multiple columns?)

The workaround I found was this:

```
TreeView{
    id: treeView
    //...
    delegate: TreeViewDelegate{
        id: item
        //...
        MouseArea{
            //...
            onClicked: function(mouseEvent){
                treeView.modelIndex( treeView.cellAtPosition( item.x + mouseEvent.x, item.y + mouseEvent.y, true ) );               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure, if it is working. Currently I am having one column.  But this will change.
My test sample only has a root node with two children. If I click on the root node, I will get the same result as if I click on the first child "QModelIndex(0,0,0x600002ed0118,GarminTreeModel(0x16faaf068))".
If I click on the second child, "QModelIndex(1,0,0x600002ed0218,GarminTreeModel(0x16faaf068))" is printed in the console.
So, if, only the first parameter differs. Interestingly, if I log index.row to the console,  I am getting 0 for the root, 1 and 2 for the child nodes.
Anyway, thank you.